# Prove statement about commutative unital ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, finitely-generated

I'm trying to solve this problem from my abstract algebra course:

> Given $A$ a commutative unital ring. Prove that the following two
> properties are equivalent:
>
> 1. Every ideal of $A$ is finitely generated.
> 2. There is no family $\{I_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ of ideals from $A$ such that $I_n\subsetneq I_{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 1$

I am confused from the second statement, it's hard to imagine for me what does that exactly mean for me to use it in my proof. I started trying to assume every ideal in $A$ can be expressed as $I=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ for some elements $a_i\in A$ (to be said, it's finitely generated), but I don't know how to get to the other statement from that.

For the reverse implication, I understand in my head that assuming that we have such a family of sets, in order for them to verify $I_n\subsetneq I_{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 1$, they must be always growing in size because they can't be equal, so that leads to an infinite amount of generators, but I don't know how that must be written correctly in a mathematic way.

How can I approach this? Any hint, answer or just help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: If $(I_n)$ is an increasing sequence of ideals, then the union $\bigcup_{n\geq1}I_n$ is an ideal and hence finitely generated.

Comment: @leoli1 Thanks! I'll see what I can get from that now.

Comment: @leoli1 So I see, if $\bigcup^\infty_{n=1} I_n$ is finitely generated, then there must be equal ideals inside the family since it's union of infinite terms, but how can I express that well? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The idea is the following: Since $\bigcup_{n\geq1}I_n$ is finitely generated, say by $a_1,\dots,a_s$, then all $a_i$ lie in on of the $I_n$. Since $I_n$ is increasing and we only have finitely many $a_i$ there has to be an index $m$ such that $a_1,\dots,a_s\in I_m$, now compare $I_m$ with the whole union.